# problem with paragraph spacing when removing hyphenation

Tags: spacing, memoir, hyphenation

I use memoir class and I would like to get a text jutified without hyphenation.
I tried 2 methods, both works but I get unwanted behavior

First one

```
\pretolerance=2000
\tolerance=2000 
\emergencystretch=10pt
```

[image]

it seem the use of `\pretolerance=2000` trigger the problem. The text is vertically aligned to fill the page. This seem to happen when they are lot of small paragraph.

Second method is to use

```
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
```

[image]

Did you have a tips for one of method described to remove unwanted behavior ?

Thanks for your light

Comment: You can't get well justified text without hyphenation.

Comment: With your first method try putting `\raggedbottom` in the preamble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that putting

```
\pretolerance=2000
\tolerance=2000
\emergencystretch=10pt
\raggedbottom % addition to original attempt
```

in the preamble solves this problem.